# What makes ribbon keyboard shortcuts differ on computers when using same language?

Tags: excel, windows, vba, ms-office, office365

I'm trying to work with keyboard shortcuts in a VBA macro. (I know, but it's critical that the macro access a command via the tool ribbon using keystrokes and no other way around it.) It all works great, but I found that the needed keystrokes vary between a test computer physically in Germany and another in the US. BOTH have German set as the Office language preference and use the same version of Office (Excel 2016 32 bit).

In Excel, For example, to get to the Fill Color tool using German, in Germany it's ALT+R,TS, but in the US it's ALT+R,H1.

Does anyone know what might cause the variance and, better yet, how to detect it in VBA so I can add conditional logic to make it work in multiple locations?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not use UI Automation?

Comment: Not allowed and not really applicable. Has to be 100% VBA (Excel/Word) add ins, which it is now and works fine except for the potential variance oddity described above. Currently it successfully detects the local Office language ID and then calls the proper keyboard shortcuts for that language interface to access a specific native tool, thus automating a task for the user.

Comment: Not allowed by whom, and what specifically makes it not applicable? After all, that *is* the standard solution to the problem you are trying to solve. In fact, using UI Automation, you don't even have the problem you are trying to solve now.

Comment: Sorry – was thinking of something else. Thanks for elaborating. We are tasked why keyboard shortcuts varied, but reading on UI Automation, I'd like to explore it. Obviously, I'm not experienced with it. Can you give me pointers? From a custom button on the tool ribbon, all the code does (via Sendkeys) is open the Excel "Fill Color" tool and then the "More Colors..." option in it, then hits ENTER. (A colored shape was already selected in the sheet, so this places its custom color into the RECENT COLORS area of the FILL COLOR tool. I would LOVE any help with getting UI Automation to do this?

Comment: If it helps... The aforementioned "button on the tool ribbon" is an XLAM Excel add in. So, all this is ran via a user clicking an XLAM add in button on the tool ribbon. (They have a choice of color buttons in a tab, each is a separate button.)

Comment: Reference material on MSDN: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). To get an idea of the kind of information that's available, you can run the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool.